# How to sort and compare the expected and actual list of WebElements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, arraylist, webdriver

I have a list of expected WebElements and Actual WebElements which I have stored in a list. I want to sort both the lists and compare the expected with the actual WebElements.

Below is the code which I have written.

```
List<WebElement> ExpList = List.of(LookingLbl,GenderLbl,MandatoryList,NameLbl,MobLbl );
        System.out.println("Expected list size is : " +ExpList.size());
        System.out.println("Expected list of Web Elements below : ");
        for(WebElement expElem : ExpList) {
            System.out.println(expElem.getText());
        }

List<WebElement> ActList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'')]"));
        System.out.println("WebElement list size is :" +ActList.size());
        System.out.println("Actual list of Web Elements below : ");
        for(WebElement elem : ActList) {
            if(elem.getText().contains("*")) {
                System.out.println(elem.getText());
            }           
        }
```

Now I want both the ExpList and ActList to be sorted and compared. How can I sort and compare the actual and expected web elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collections` to sort the lists:

```
Collections.sort(ExpList);
Collections.sort(ActList);
```

And then use JUnit assertion to assert they are equal:

```
Assert.assertEquals(ExpList, ActList);
```

Comment: No That's not working..Collections.sort(ExpList). This is not showing me any options inside sort as ExpList . If I forcefully use this Collections.sort(ExpList);it is giving error on 'sort' as below.          Cast Argument 'ExpList' to List<T>